# How to Select the SAP HANA table in python

Tags: python, hana

I have connected to SAP HANA by using python

```
connection = pyodbc.connect(DSN = 'PROD-HANA')
```

I have a View in SAP HANA which is under prd - global - Calculated_View_Name

In python I am selecting the values from the tables

```
with connection.cursor() as crsr:
    crsr.execute("SELECT * FROM prd.global.Calculated_View_Name")
```

I am getting the following error

```
ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB32 DLL][HDBODBC32] Syntax error or access violation;257 sql syntax error: database name not allowed in single-container mode: line 1 col 15 (at pos 15) (257) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong with the query?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have used fully qualified name for database object including the database name

As error indicates, your HANA database platform is in single-container mode

So you should omit database name on your SELECT query from FROM clause

So instead of

```
prd.global.Calculated_View_Name
```

You can use

```
global.Calculated_View_Name
```